# C# JSON Deserialization Keeps Changing Date Format

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, deserialization

I have a following method that takes strings, deserialize then serialize json.

This is my body value with StatusDateTimeUTC in UTC format

```
body = "{   \"IdentityNumber\" :660045,\r\n \"ResolutionStatusId\" :3,\r\n \"StatusDateTimeUTC\" :\"2020-11-15T11:37:08.0000000Z\",\r\n \"OutcomeId\" :3}"
```

```
private string BuildJson<T>(string body, string operation)
{
   AMSDto<T> aMSDto = new AMSDto<T>();
   aMSDto.Body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body);
           
   NistMapping.AddHeaders<T>(aMSDto, operation);
   return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aMSDto);
}
```

**after deserialize, my StatusDateTimeUTC format changes to 2020-11-15T11:37:08+00:00, but I want to keep the UTC format 2020-11-15T11:37:08.0000000Z**

```
"Body": {
        "IdentityNumber": 660045,
        "ResolutionStatusId": 3,
        "StatusDateTimeUTC": "2020-11-15T11:37:08+00:00",
        "OutcomeId": 3
    }
```

I have tried both the following mentioned in other threads, but it didn't work.

```
aMSDto.Body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
      DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
});
```

```
microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};

aMSDto.Body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(body, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

Comment: Why do you care about the seriized format of DateTimes. A serialized object exists to be deserialized  not read by a human. You should be able to do what you want by writing a _custom converter_  but this will affect all objects of type DateTime: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. But, I guess you want to serialize an object (the object is an instance of a custom class) to a string and then deserialize that string back to the same object.
If that's the case, you can use the same serializer settings while serializing and deserializing the object.

```cs
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, settings);
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject&lt;YourObjectType&gt;(jsonString, settings);
```

Comment: Yes this is what I did, but the date format still changed